# Sharepoint Discussion board - Reply to reply

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-discussion-board

How we can implement reply to reply features in Sharepoint discussion Board. I have one a application, in that i have to implement this functionality as well. i got some solutions for replying to the root of the topic. But i need that, we have to reply for a specific post. Please help me by proving your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use this method [SPUtility.CreateNewDiscussionReply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.createnewdiscussionreply.aspx) with specific post item.